# Оценка первой верстки (+ вопрос)

Tags: css3, html, html5, css, вёрстка

Оцените верстку и написание кода. **Возможно имеются ошибки, какие именно?**
Основной задачей для меня являлось сделать как можно точно по PSD макету. Нужно было расширение фона блоков по ширине на 100% экрана, а контент в них по центру.

1. Валидацию прошел.
2. По кроссбраузерности, вроде все нормально, только в IE 8 не поддерживается background: cover; и фоновая заставка второго блока не расширяется. Пока ищу варианты для IE8.
   Вот ссылка на [страницу](http://lesenciya.com/).
3. Также сделали замечание, что во многих случаях было использовано позиционирование, убрал и поправил.

Вопрос: **Как лучше использовать свои шрифты?** Подгружать через файл стилей либо загружать в коде HTML через Google fonts, если такой шрифт есть в базе. Хотя не вижу разницы, оба варианта отлично отображаются при правильном использовании.

Comment: Если используете <!DOCTYPE HTML>, тогда почему не используете теги - header, section, article, nav, footer и др.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Пока только учусь, теперь буду применять html5 элементы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Про шрифты**

Шрифты, сторонние библиотеки типа jquery, html5shiv и прочее луше грузить, конечно, с гуглей. Во-первых, велика вероятность того, что идентичный файл будет прокеширован. Во-вторых, эти библиотеки имеют свойство обновлятся. В случае со шрифтами это важно, так как большинство из них кривые/косые.

**По верстке**

1. Я бы рекомендовал отказаться от наследования/каскадирования. К чему такие селекторы: **#clients .comment p**? Вы через две недели уже будете боятся перемещать **.comment**. Попробуйте с ходу разобраться, из каких учатков стилей собирается кнопка "Plans & Pricing". Гораздо лучше создать один класс **.button** и убрать все стили в него.
2. **#clients h3** аналогично, создайте вы просто класс **.title** и проставляйте заголовкам.
3. **НИКОГДА** не следует матчится на теги. Используйте классы. Исключением может быть файл сброса дефолтовых стилей и какой-нибудь вырожденный блок, например, **.wysiwyg**, в контекст которого попадает текст, вбиваемый через WYSIWYG редактор.
4. Опять же, зачем такой селектор **#header, .your-domain, .wleft-row img, .com, .finner, .icon-1, .icon-2, .icon-3, .icon-4, #clients, .plans_inner { margin: 0 auto; }**? Уберите в отдельный класс это свойство или группу свойств.
5. Не вижу смысла использовать айдишники в верстке.
6. Почитайте про БЕМ / верстку независимыми блоками / контекстно независимую верстку. Хотя, судя по коду, вы уже читали. Это точно ваш первый сайт или вы так рекламитесь?
7. Завязывайте с обтеканием. Обтекания надо сбрасывать, обтекаемые элементы создают свой поток кода. Ну и вообще в целом не самое прозрачное поведение. Попробуйте inline-block.

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробный ответ!
Про шрифты теперь понятно :)
1. А что делать тогда, когда у всех блоков разные стили p? Создавать для каждого параграфа свой личный класс со стилем?<br>
3. Вместо такого кода: ul li{}, лучше сделать так .list{}?
4. То есть лучше создать отдельный класс типо:
.center {
margin: 0 auto;
}
И применять так:
<div class="header center"></div>
5. Насчет этого сейчас почитаю :)
6. Куда мне рекламироваться, когда у меня куча проблем в вёрстке :)
7. До этого я использовал в большинстве случаев позиционирование, потом перешел на float. Но всегда знал, что-то не то делаю.

Comment: И как насчет bootstrap?

Comment: 1. У параграфа, по идее, только отступ должен быть из стилей. Так что все настройки текста должны прийти от родителя. Есть вот у вас, например, есть блок для статьи .article, то в нем прописаны стили текста. Внутри параграфы получают стили от статьи. Есть у вас, напрмиер, блок для превью ленты новостей .feed, то в нем прописаны другие стили, а параграфы внутри их так же получают стили.

Comment: 2.Да, только тогда .list {} и .list__item {}  
Повторюсь, что если это кусок контента, вбиваемый, например, через wysiwyg редактор, то конечно же никто не будет проставлять эти классы, набивая статью в админке. В этом случае уже можно заматчиться на ul или li, но только в контексте того блока, в котором у вас контент. Я вычленяю такие куски блоком .wysiwyg в контексте которого тегам уже проставлены стили - буллеты списков, отступы и т.д.

Comment: 3. Конкретно для этой задачи можно создать блок .region / .column / .wrapper, в него прописать width: 960px; padding: 0 20px; margin: 0 auto; будет у вас такой независимый ни от чего блок задающий колонну сайта. В него уже пихать шапки, тела страницы, подвалы.

Comment: 6 Нет ничего лучше покоординатного позиционирования, явно проставленных ширин и т.д., конечно. И браузер и раработчику, всем легко. Но часто нужно задавать колонки, делать плитки, отталкиваться от контента и т.д. inline-block один из лучших инструментов - самое прозрачное поведение, универсален для многих задач. Иногда, конечно, приходится прибегать и к табличкам, и даже к обтеканию, но большинство типовых задач можно решить позиционированием и inline-block`ом.

Comment: Бутстрап я недолюбливаю. Я как бы сам себе бутстрап. Для прототипирования, например, это хорошая штука, но когда есть уникальный дизайн и верстальщик, то скрипач не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше добавлять через файл стилей. Не очень хорошо, когда подтягиваются файлы из сторонних ресурсов.

Comment: согласен, по возможности, нужно делать проект изолированным от сторонних ресурсов.

Comment: Эм, практика CDN c вами категорически не согласна.